# Why does the ABC song's music differ in China from that of most other countries?

Tags: history

Why is the Chinese version of the ABC song different to most of the rest of the world?

Most of the world has a fast "LMNOP" and a whole song similar to this:

[image]

In Britain, America, France, Germany, The Netherlands — they all have fast "LMNOP". The second half has more minor variations across languages, generally to fit in the syllables of their words for W and Y, but the tune remains pretty much the same.

The song they are taught to learn the English alphabet is the traditional English native one.

But the Chinese song taught for the English alphabet already begins to differ at L:

[image]

And the ending is different too.

What is the history of this song and why is it used instead of the mainstream version? Is this in relation to the different performance of music practice in China?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137448/discussion-on-question-by-theonlygusti-why-is-the-chinese-abc-song-different).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn’t seem to be about music practice or theory and might be a better fit at Music Fans or ELU.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question. It is about music practice: the practice in various countries of singing different versions of a well-known song. This has clear practical applications for performance and teaching and well as relating to music history.

Comment: @Aaron history and cultrual yes, but not what we typically cover. Music Fans has had more things in this vein with the same melody over different lyrics.